# Optionally printing the last login time using SSHD

Tags: authentication, sshd

I'm trying to control access to Linux and Solaris servers, and have a requirement that some users should see a last login time message (e.g. `Last login: Thu Jun 27 09:42:20 2013`) and some shouldn't.

Is it possible to instruct `sshd` to print the last login time for some users only?

Notes:

- I am aware of the `PrintLastLog` option in `sshd_config`. However, it cannot be used in a `Match` block.
- I am aware that I might be able to use the `pam_listfile` and `pam_lastlog` PAM modules to achieve the effect I'm after.

Answer (score 1):

utmp, wtmp, btmp and variants such as utmpx, wtmpx and btmpx are files on Unix-like systems that keep track of all logins and logouts to the system [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utmp]

Maybe you could try renaming or removing these files and the last login message will no longer appear.

NOTE: I tried to do this on AIX and even when the last command did not display any records the last login message continues to appear. It was after removing the /etc/security/lastlog file that I was able to get rid of the message.

Comment: Seems like it might work, although wouldn't the OS simply start writing to a new file with the same name?

Comment: Yes, it will create a new file with the same name so you need to manage that. For example on AIX instead of removing /etc/security/lastlog you could try creating a symb link to /dev/null: ln -sf /dev/null /etc/security/lastlog.

Comment: I like the idea of creating a symbolic link to /dev/null. Unfortunately I need to print the last login time for some users and not for others, so I can't get rid of the information.